# How to disable checkBox if other checkBox is checked c#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have an array of checkBox in my windows form application. I am wondering is there a way to disable that array of checkBox if one or more checkBox in that array is checked?

for example:
if A is checked, B,C,D,E is disabled
if A, and C is checked, B, D, E is disabled

Sorry for the confusion. In the following example, A, C, E is checked. What I want is B, D then is disable

```
[x]A []B [x]C []D [x]E
```

This is my array list

Another example:

This example showed D is checked, then A, B, C and E should be disabled

```
[]A []B []C [x]D []E
```

Code:

```
CheckBox[] myCheckBoxArray = new CheckBox[5];

myCheckBoxArray[0] = checkBoxA 
myCheckBoxArray[1] = checkBoxB
myCheckBoxArray[2] = checkBoxC 
myCheckBoxArray[3] = checkBoxD 
myCheckBoxArray[4] = checkBoxE
```

Comment: Wouldn't a radio group be better suited for this?

Comment: If checking A disables C, then how would anyone ever get both A and C checked?

Comment: but if I use a radio button, then I cannot select multiple items

Comment: @DragonBorn Are you only referring to one group of check boxes?

Comment: @adv12, you misread my question

Comment: But if you're disabling all of the other options when one is selected, how would you select them?  Or is it that some options can be selected together, but other options cannot be?

Comment: @DragonBorn, I reread your question and am still wondering the same thing.

Comment: @abramlimpin, in my windows form, I drag 5 checkBoxes from the toolbox. Not sure if this is what you meant my group

Comment: show us the GUI/form

Comment: I concur with @adv12, you state "A is checked, B,C,D,E is disabled", therefore A and C cannot be checked at the same time. Please clarify your question as it makes no sense at the moment.

Comment: @DragonBorn I think you should try CheckedListBox control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi all sorry for the confusion, I've edited my post for example

Comment: does my edited post make sense?

Comment: No, it still doesn't make sense. How do eg A, C, E ever all become selected if all other checkboxes are disabled once one is selected?

Comment: @DragonBorn when you say disabled do you mean unchecked?

Comment: @ElectricRouge I mean checkBox.Enabled = false;

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is a simple 'if' statement:

```
if (checkBoxA.Checked == true)
{
    checkBoxB.Checked = false;
    ....
}
```

And so on and so forth. You can also check multiple boxes at the same time, using the '&&' operator, like so:

```
if (checkBoxA.Checked == true && checkBoxB.Checked == false)
{ do.something(); }
```

To apply this to your array, simply append the following:

```
if (checkBoxA.Checked == true)
{
    myCheckBoxArray[i].Checked = false;
}
```

You can't group sections of an array in the manner that you're asking - you might be able to call certain array members if they met a certain condition, however you do not necessarily *know* their condition before you change their 'Checked' status. In this context, you must either change the entire array, or each checkbox one-by-one. Alternatively, create your array in your if statement. This is an expensive process, however, and largely pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my question

```
 CheckBox[] checkBox1 = new CheckBox[5];
            checkBox1 [0] = checkBoxA;
            checkBox1 [1] = checkBoxB;
            checkBox1 [2] = checkBoxC;
            checkBox1 [3] = checkBoxD;
            checkBox1 [4] = checkBoxE;

            foreach(CheckBox items in checkBox1 )
            {
                if (!items.Checked)
                {
                    items.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You wanted to do this on button click?

Comment: Did you mean to make them uncheckable by the user? I'm sorry, I incorrectly assumed that you merely wanted to ensure that only certain checkboxes could be checked at a given time. bear in mind, however, that this method of yours simply disables the entire array, regardless of check status.

Comment: @ElectricRouge, not but button click, but a dropdown box. But I have fixed my question.